# How to disable the touchpad when I use the trackpoint in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mouse, thinkpad

I have recently installed Ubuntu (and its derivatives Xubuntu and Kubuntu) on my laptop.

On my computer, I have both a touchpad and a trackpoint. In Windows, the touchpad is disabled when I use the trackpoint.

Is there any way to recreate this in Linux?

Comment: Check out [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad) site

Answer (score 1):

I Googled and Googled for a fix for this exact problem and this is what I came up with to suit my system:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#Change /dev/input/event13 to your trackstick event
    cat /dev/input/event13 > /tmp/mousemove &
#initialize counter to prevent garbage file from growing
    i="0";
    while true ; do 
        i=$[$i+1];
        #variables  
        oldchecksum=${newchecksum};
        newchecksum=`md5sum /tmp/mousemove | awk '{print $1}'`
        #see if trackpad is already disabled
        if [ "$trackpad" = "off" ]; then

            #compare previous checksum to current if they're same trackstick is not moving
            if [ "$oldchecksum" = "$newchecksum" ]; then
                #make sure trackpad is enabled
                xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 1;
                trackpad="on";
            fi

        else

            #compare previous checksum to current if they're different trackstick is moving
            if [ "$oldchecksum" != "$newchecksum" ]; then
                #disable trackpad
                xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 0;
                trackpad="off";
            fi

        fi

        #check for count to keep poll file smaller
        if [ "$i" = "300" ]; then
            echo '' > /tmp/mousemove;
            i="0";
            newchecksum=`md5sum /tmp/mousemove | awk '{print $1}'`
        fi
            #sleep for 1 second so we don't eat up resources
            #if the update speed is not fast enough for you a smaller number such as .75 may be better
            sleep 1;
    done
```

Since I run fluxbox on arch I added the script call in my `~/.fluxbox/apps`

Only caveat I could find was that if you manage to pkill cat as root, which this script must be run as to access the mouse event, you’ll kill the script, at the same time if you kill the script and don’t kill cat it will continue to run until you either run out of space in `/tmp`, pkill cat, or reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple trick (hack really):

```
xinput set-prop "DLL07B0:01 044E:120B" "Synaptics Finger" 100 1000 100
```

What it does is set wrong pressures parameter (min > max), and some ridiculous finger size.

```
Synaptics Finger
    32 bit, 3 values, low, high, press. 

Option "FingerLow" "integer"
    When finger pressure drops below this value, the driver counts it as a release. Property: "Synaptics Finger"

Option "FingerHigh" "integer"
    When finger pressure goes above this value, the driver counts it as a touch. Property: "Synaptics Finger"
```

So, the driver will count even as a press when the pressure > 1000 and pressure < 100 which is logically impossible.